# How do I make this program add two boxes rather than one?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble with this code. I don't understand how to add another box apart from the one that it already adds with ajax within the code when I press the link *Add more*. I want to be able to add two text boxes when I press the *add more* link, one for hobby and another one for age but I only get one. What I tried was on the on click function I tried to add another var html_box2 but it did not work out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#main {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
    <div class="my-form">
        <form role="form" method="post">
            <p class="text-box">
                <label for="box1">Box <span class="box-number">1</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box1" />
                <a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a>
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
        var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
        if( 5 < n ) {
            alert('Stop it!');
            return false;
        }
        var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="boxes[]" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
        box_html.hide();
        $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
        box_html.fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
    $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
        $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $('.box-number').each(function(index){
                $(this).text( index + 1 );
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Philip There is nothing wrong with this question and how it was asked. It appears like a valid question asked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines of code add one box

```
    var box_html = $('<p class="text-box">whatever goes here</p>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');
```

You can copy and modify them to create another box like

```
    var box_html = $('<p class="text-box">whatever goes here</p>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');

    var box_html2 = $('<p class="text-box">whatever has to go here</p>');
    box_html2.hide();
    $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html2);
    box_html2.fadeIn('slow');
```